# Subclassing private classes in a library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So we have a library with header files as below (for instance):

**Public**

- MyCustomClass.h (subclasses MyClass)

**Private**

- MyClass.h

When this is imported into an app however it then complains that it can't find `MyClass.h`. This is fair enough. Its `#import`ed into `MyCustomClass.h` and yet its hidden.

So I changed it to a forward class declaration `@class MyClass`. Now it complains that I can't use a forward declaration for a super class (also makes sense).

How can I get around this then? I need to subclass something, but I only want people using the library to have access to the child class, not the super class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ObjC, how do I hide implementation a superclass's methods in a subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507417/in-objc-how-do-i-hide-implementation-a-superclasss-methods-in-a-subclass)

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, but I'm actually looking to hide the existence of that class all together and not the methods. I want people to be able to subclass MyCustomClass, and use all the methods but not subclass the original MyClass (MyCustomClass overrides some methods you see - so I want to force people to use MyCustomClass over MyClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing a library, and you want clients to instantiate MyCustomClass which inherits from MyClass. But clients should not ever instantiate MyClass.

**Approach 1**: You don't actually need or want to hide MyClass. You just want to avoid instantiating instances of it.

- a) Make its constructor private
- b) Create a factory method that creates instances of MyCustomClass.

The factory might be part of MyClass, or it could be elsewhere.

```
@implemenation MyClass
+ (MyCustomClass*) createWith: (Param*) someData;
```

**Approach 2**: consider composition rather than inheritance.  Let MyCustomClass *own* an object of type MyClass, and let it do all the work:

```
 @implementation MyCustomClass
 @property (nonatomic,strong) MyClass* myClassInstance;
 - (void) doSomething 
 {
      [self.myClassInstance doSomething];
 }
```

Since clients can't subclass MyClass anyway, the inheritance is an implementation detail. Don't inherit when you don't need to.

**Approach 3**: Are you sure you really want to expose MyCustomClass? Is it really an object, or is it a protocol?  Perhaps your library should offer the interface publicly, and both MyClass and MyCustomClass are private implementations.

Comment: there is no private constructor in ObjC

Comment: Can't you make `init` private?

Comment: there is no private method in ObjC. you can hide the declaration, but since `init` is defined in `NSObject`, you can't do anything to hide it

Comment: Approach 2 is how we solved this issue. Its a touch "messy" - feels wrong, but is the only way we can really solve this. :) Many thanks!

Comment: Composition is BETTER than inheritance.  It feels messier, but it's not. Reserve inheritance for situations where it's the only answer.

Comment: Actually, you can disable `init` - with the `unavailable` attribute